# atoi() from hex representation string

Tags: c, atoi

Need to make int from hex representation string like `"0xFA"` or better `"FA"`. Need something like `atoi("FA")`. Is there are any standard solutions for that?

Comment: Something like [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol), you mean?

Comment: [Know your tools](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Try to use [strtol()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html):

```
strtol("FA", NULL, 16);
```

Comment: Note: it also works with `0xFA`: "(optional) prefix (0x or 0X) indicating hexadecimal base (applies only when the base is 16 or ​0​)"

Comment: For unsigned, you should use strtoul() to properly handle strings like "0x81234567", otherwise you will get 0xFFFFFFFF returned.